# Calculation of rank according to supplier table & sales table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2014; I attached a `purchase` table (from suppliers) and sales table.

First, I need to use a sales table based on the rankings from the purchase table, product bought first from supplier table sold first in sales table (FIFO method).

How do I do these calculations?

Attached is a rank calculation in the `purchase` table.

Thanks.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Purchases
(
     PurID INT,
     ItemID VARCHAR(5),
     Qty INT,
     UnitPrice INT
)

INSERT INTO Purchases (PurID, ItemID, Qty, UnitPrice) 
VALUES ('1', 'A', '50', '3'),
       ('2', 'A', '60', '2'),
       ('3', 'A', '90', '6'),
       ('5', 'B', '5', '5'),
       ('6', 'B', '15', '4')

CREATE TABLE Sales_5
(
     InvID INT,
     ItemID VARCHAR(5),
     Qty INT,
     UnitPrice_Fifo INT
)

INSERT INTO Sales_5 (InvID, ItemID, Qty, UnitPrice_Fifo)
VALUES ('1', 'A', '100', '250'),
       ('2', 'A', '100', '560'),
       ('5', 'B', '10', '45'),
       ('6', 'B', '10', '40')
```

Rank from table Purchases:

```
 with PurchasesbyFifo AS 
 (
     select 
         itemid,
         Purid,
         rank () over (partition by itemid order by Purid ASC) as rank_BY_Fifo 
     from
         [Purchases] 
 )
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.  Also, explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @syyt, Please provide the joining key and also desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Select X.*
From
(
    select 
        P.ItemID, 
        P.PurId, 
        Rank () Over 
        (
            Partition By 
            (
                Select Min(S.InvID)
                From Sales_5 As S With(NoLock)
                Where S.ItemID = P.ItemID
            ) 
            Order By P.PurId ASC
        )
        As rank_BY_Fifo 
    from Purchases As P With(NoLock)
) As X
Order By rank_BY_Fifo
```

Comment: after the example base you have provided
I think I understood, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My opinion, you need to 'Purchase date' and 'Sale date' columns in tables.

FIFO (First in, first out) methodology uses movement date values to ordering data.

Because, Unique Id column of movement tables not equal to movement orders in real world (Generally).

Use milisecond detailed datetime values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a date column in a purchase table
How to use PURID column as the first product rating
Sold in sales table?